# QtSql Not Showing Query Results Anywhere

Tags: c++, qt

My SQL results were showing on Label but then I decided to drop that specific and made a new one.
Then I changed the query to be executed but nothing shows up anymore!
I have been debugging for the past 2 hours to no avail.
I used boolean to check if the query was executed and it showed '1' however, when I print the query.value, it shows nothing.

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("SELECT * FROM artists;");
QString name = query.value(0).toString();
ui->label_2->setText(name);
```

I can also confirm that my database is connected since it shows '1' on if (db.open()).

I have imported sql in the .pro file, obviously.

I use mariadb => QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

Could it be a case of permission denied?

Comment: Maybe there was a database error. You should add code to check if the exec() succeeded. In my Qt code I always check the result and take action on failure.

Comment: I think you need to call `query.next()` after `query.exec()` to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As drescherjm pointed out, `query.next()` must be used to move the pointer of query forward.